# Offering account deletion in your app via a website

Tags: ios, mobile-application

In Apple's guidelines about [Offering account deletion in your app](https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app), it states the following:

> If people need to visit a website to finish deleting their account,
> include a link directly to the page on your website where they can
> complete the process.

However, in the FAQ section of the same page, it states:

> If my app links out to the default web browser for account creation,
> does it still need to offer account deletion within the app?
>
> Yes. Additionally, note that linking out to the default web browser to
> sign in or register an account provides a poor user experience and is
> not appropriate, per App Store Review Guideline 4.

Given the above information, would having a button in the app that says "request account deletion" that opens a website to complete account deletion requests be compliant with Apple's guidelines? In other words, is it ok to just have a website for the account deletion request process (link to this website will be available from the app), or is it required that the account deletion request process be completed on the app itself?

Answer (score 1):

Everything needs to happen within the app, either natively or via an embedded browser for both user sign-ups and user account deletion.

From my experience, Apple doesn't like "Request" or "Deactivate" as a default modus operandi and prefers only "DELETE" and "IMMEDIATELY"

See https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/patterns/managing-accounts/

> If you help people create an account within your app or game, you must
> also help them delete it, not just deactivate it. In addition to
> following the guidelines below, be sure to understand and comply with
> your region’s legal requirements related to account deletion and the
> right to be forgotten.

Also see https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app/

> **If my app links out to the default web browser for account creation, does it still need to offer account deletion within the app?**
>
> Yes. Additionally, note that linking out to the default web browser to
> sign in or register an account provides a poor user experience and is
> not appropriate, per App Store Review Guideline 4.

See the responses below from Apple on both issues.

> Guideline 4.0 - Design
>
> We noticed that the user is taken to the default web browser to sign
> in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to enable users to sign
> in or register for an account in the app.
>
> You may also choose to implement the Safari View Controller API to
> display web content within your app. The Safari View Controller allows
> the display of a URL and inspection of the certificate from an
> embedded browser in an app so that customers can verify the webpage
> URL and SSL certificate to confirm they are entering their sign in
> credentials into a legitimate page.

and

> Guideline 5.1.1(v) - Data Collection and Storage
>
> We noticed that your app supports account creation but does not
> include an option to initiate account deletion that meets all the
> requirements. Specifically:
>
> - Your app only offers to deactivate the account. Temporarily deactivating accounts is not sufficient to meet the account deletion
>   requirement.
>
> The process for initiating account deletion must provide a consistent,
> transparent experience for App Store users.
>
> Next Steps
>
> It would be appropriate to revise your app to address the issues
> identified above and resubmit your app once the account deletion
> option meets all the requirements.
>
> If you believe your current account deletion option meets all the
> requirements, either because your app operates in a highly-regulated
> industry or for some other reason, reply to this message and provide
> additional information or documentation.
>
> Resources
>
> - Review frequently asked questions and learn more about the account deletion requirements.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes you have to provide account deletion or account deactivate option on website as well.

Comment: To clarify my question, is it ok to just have a website for the account deletion request process (link to this website will be available from the app), or is it required that the account deletion request process be completed on the app itself?

Comment: It’s clearly mention in the guidelines: apps that support account creation must let users initiate deletion of their account within the app.

Comment: So does that mean, as long as the deletion is initiated within the app (a button within the app that opens a website), it's fine if the deletion process is completed on a website?

Comment: Yes that’s fine. Refer this: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12m75xbj

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app